# Getting value from a collection without using the Clone trait

Tags: rust, readonly, move-semantics, traits

Is it possible to get a value from a collection and apply a method to it which accepts only `self` and not `&self`?

**Minimal Working Example**

What I would like to write is something akin to:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn get<B>(key: i32, h: HashMap<i32, Vec<(i32, B)>>) -> i32 where B: Into<i32> {
    let v: &Vec<(i32, B)> = h.get(&key).unwrap();
    let val: &B = v.first().unwrap().1;

    // Do something to be able to call into
    // I only need the value as read-only
    // Does B have to implement the Clone trait?
    return val.into();
}
```

I have tried in vain to dribble `mut` here and there to try to appease compiler error after compiler error, but this is really a fool's errand.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn get<B>(key: i32, mut h: HashMap<i32, Vec<(i32, B)>>) -> i32 where B: Into<i32> {
    let mut v: &Vec<(i32, B)> = h.get_mut(&key).unwrap();
    let ref mut val: B = v.first_mut().unwrap().1;
    return (*val).into();
}
```

Is this sort of thing even possible or does `B` have to implement the `Clone` trait?

I've also tried:

- Unsafe
- Raw pointers

I've not tried:

- `Box`
- Other Rust constructs that I have not encountered,
  I mention this to explicitly state that I have not
  omitted any approaches that I know of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to get a value from a collection and apply a method to it which accepts only `self` and not `&self`?

In general, no, not without removing it from the collection. The collection owns the value. Methods that take `self` want to transform the item while consuming the ownership, so you have to transfer ownership.

Cloning or copying an item creates a new item with new ownership that you can then give to the method.

In your particular case, you can *almost* get away with this exciting `where` clause:

```
where for<'a> &'a B: Into<i32>
```

Except `From<&i32>` is not implemented for `i32`. You can write a trait that does what you want though:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

trait RefInto<T> {
    fn into(&self) -> T;
}

impl RefInto<i32> for i32 {
    fn into(&self) -> i32 { *self }
}

fn get<B>(key: i32, h: HashMap<i32, Vec<(i32, B)>>) -> i32
    where B: RefInto<i32>
{
    let v = h.get(&key).unwrap();
    let val = &v.first().unwrap().1;

    val.into()
}

// ----

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(42, vec![(100, 200)]);
    let v = get(42, map);
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

Alternatively, you might be able to make use of [`Borrow`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html):

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::borrow::Borrow;

fn get<B>(key: i32, h: HashMap<i32, Vec<(i32, B)>>) -> i32
    where B: Borrow<i32>
{
    let v = h.get(&key).unwrap();
    let val = &v.first().unwrap().1;

    *val.borrow()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function consumes the `HashMap`. I'm assuming this is your intent and that you therefore don't care about any of its content except the one element you wish to convert into an `i32`.

You can use the `HashMap::remove` method to extract a value. You can then use `Vec::swap_remove` to extract the first element.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn get<B>(key: i32, mut h: HashMap<i32, Vec<(i32, B)>>) -> i32 where B: Into<i32> {
    h.remove(&key)
        .unwrap()
        .swap_remove(0)
        .1
        .into()
}
```

If `B` is cheap to copy, then it makes more sense to write a function where it is copied.

The above doesn't handle errors. A version with error handling could look like this:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn get<B>(key: i32, mut h: HashMap<i32, Vec<(i32, B)>>) -> Option<i32> where B: Into<i32> {
    h.remove(&key)
        .and_then(|mut vec| {
            if vec.is_empty() { None } 
            else { Some(vec.swap_remove(0).1.into()) }
        })
}
```

`Vec::swap_remove` isn't ideal. The functionality of moving an element at an arbitrary index out of the vector without any other work would be handled by the `IndexMove` trait which doesn't yet exist though.

Comment: I want the `HashMap` to still associate the key with the same vector that it had.

Comment: @FilipAllberg A.B.'s point is *very* important though. By accepting a `h: HashMap`, you are transferring the ownership of the map *to the function*. It basically doesn't matter what the function does to the map as nothing else will ever be able to use the map.

Comment: Noted, now using `&h`. Thanks!